# Should I use SQL Azure to store product descriptions and links to images in Azure Blob

Tags: database-design, nosql, azure-sql-database

For an html/Css/JQuery public Azure website to be coded using Zurb Foundation html5 responsive framework, I'd like to use SQL Azure (web edition) to store product descriptions and links to images that I store in Azure Blob Storage.

Therefore I would want to link my SQL Azure to my Zurb Foundation Azure Website and have an easy interface (I'm an absolute beginner in dba) to insert and update product descriptions. I'd like to be able to import the product descriptions, links and whatever other useful info for SEO from csv files.

Will a relational db like SQL azure perform well for this application (even if it scales to a few hundred to say three thousand concurrent users) or should I select from a document database or key/value database application (mongoDB, CouchDB etc?) that I would host in Azure ?

Comment: Really any key/value store would work, I think. If you've settled on using Azure, it may end up being simpler to use a Microsoft product that is known to work well in that context.

Comment: Tx. So if key/value is a better fit than Azure SQL would that equal to Azure Table Storage within the Azure cloud stack ? What would be a scenario where Azure SQL would be the better fit to store product catalog info pulled from csv files?

Comment: Usually the OLTP data would go into a relational database and the blobs might live elsewhere, perhaps in a key/value store if they're large enough. I don't recommend using key/value for all of it; sorry if I wasn't clear about that.